# How to make modal window open dynamic content and change url?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, routes, modal-dialog

I would like to make modal window open different routing like this website  http://architizer.com/projects/rauchkuchlhaus-auf-der-seewiese-am-schliersee-1/

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? The users who read your question should know exactly what you want without having to leave this website.

Comment: Please provide more information to the question. Post image for final results you want to achieve is better than provide a link. Also, showing your latest progress effort is also important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is:

1. Create route state for modal window
2. Put modal opening logic inside `onEnter` property (will be running when the route is changed to current state).
3. Finally all items(which should open new modals) should have references to change route with needed parameters `ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal1'})"`.

You can find an answer in common questions for [ui-router modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state)

```
$stateProvider.state("items.add", {
url: "/add",
onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "items/add",
        resolve: {
          item: function() { new Item(123).get(); }
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
          $scope.dismiss = function() {
            $scope.$dismiss();
          };

          $scope.save = function() {
            item.update().then(function() {
              $scope.$close(true);
            });
          };
        }]
    }).result.finally(function() {
        $state.go('^');
    });
}]
});
```